# Postgres return multiple columns from subquery

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance

I have found older posts but I'm curious if there is any better solution for my case.

I have working code but it is really slow. I tried to return two columns in subquery but I have an error (the subquery must return only one column).

Example: I'm JOINing a lot of tables and I need to return two columns. Lets call the table contracts and I need columns points and points_before.

```sql
    SELECT
    random things to return as default from JOINs and table workers

    (SELECT SUM(s.points)
              FROM contracts s
                       a lot of JOINs with WHERE as personal_points,

    (SELECT SUM(s.points_before)
       FROM contracts s
                       a lot of JOINs with WHERE as personal_points_before,

FROM workers p
```

How can I reduce this to only one SELECT for both points?

Comment: Can you try to reduce your query to a smaller example? It's not easy to dig through the random indentation you use. Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Is it better now? Sorry, I'm new here, and I'm not so good with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the subquery into the FROM clause as a lateral join.

```
SELECT
    random things to return as default from JOINs and table workers
    ,ss.*
FROM workers p
, LATERAL (SELECT SUM(s.points) as  personal_points
            ,SUM(s.points_before) as personal_points_before
            FROM contracts s
                 a lot of JOINs with WHERE
        ) as ss
```

Comment: Could you please explain what ss.* means? I'm getting this error right now:

ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 22:                    AND pra.id_pracovnici > 0) as ss

Comment: both `ss` are the same

Comment: I can't fix the syntax without seeing the query, - oops missing comma. *edit*

Comment: Here is syntax: https://pastebin.com/GGjpvxbR

Comment: `, LATERAL` instead of `JOIN LATERAL`

Comment: Not working: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 7: . LATERAL (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(s.a_netto_body, 0)) as osobni...

Comment: sorry dot should be a comma

Comment: Finally working, I'm gonna test it on a bigger query. Thanks a lot for now.

Comment: Before using LITERAL: Query complete 00:01:41.905 after LITERAL: 
Query complete 00:00:50.024. Still not the best but much better! Thanks.

Comment: twice as fast by having half as many sub queries, what more can be expected?

Comment: perhaps look at using common table expressions insread, but you will probably need to make larger changes.

Comment: This solution did what it should, there is no problem but I will have to run it on much more data so it will take 1 minute for each record (1409). So I have to optimaze it much more.